# Lucene field not searchable

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

**UPDATED ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I created a program that pulls in content from a database and then indexes it.  During this process, I build a string variable called searchField which consists of various different information.  Once this string is built, I make the following call.

```
doc.add(new Field("search", this.stripHTMLTags(searchField), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

I know that the string is not empty, because I put in a print statement to show the contents and the right data is making it to the doc.add().

When I search key words what do in fact show up in the searchField, I get no hits.

I'm not sure what other details to provide, and I'm sure there is more needed,  please help me help you understand better and hopefully this can get solved!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to make sure, do you add document itself to the index? Also, how do you do your search?

Comment: I suggest that you describe how you build your index, the Analyzer you use, an example document and an example query you run which should get hits but doesn't. BTW, this is a great user name for a Lucene user...

Comment: Can you check the output of stripHTMLTags(searchField)?

Comment: Lucene framework behave weird for some of the input types. Maybe if you can share whatever you put in the print statement, the exact query to db; this can get a proper answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
doc.add(new Field("search", this.stripHTMLTags(searchField), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

Comment: I see that you changed the Field.Store to YES.  Reading the manual, I see that will in fact make it show up in the index.  So you did actually answer my question.  However, it also says that you shouldn't Store large bodies of text, which searchField will be.  The problem I'm having is that after I index my searchField, I can't seem to search any of the terms that were in the searchField string.  I will revise my above question to reflect this new problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you index it to a file directory and then use [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) to look into what being indexed. Luke is the best tool to debug the Lucene related issues.

Now my hunch is that you are using different analyzers while indexing and searching. Make sure your index and search operations use the same analyzer.

Comment: Kind of funny the tool you recommend is the same name as the OP